# Closure of intersection of sets

Tags: real-analysis

Given a set $A$, use $A'$ to denote all its limit points, and $\overline A$ to denote its closure, i.e. $\overline A  = A' \cup A$. My question is, given two arbitrary sets $A,B$, does $\overline {A \cap B}  = \overline A  \cap \overline B $ hold? If not, can we show some counter example?

I can show $\overline {A \cap B}  \subseteq \overline A  \cap \overline B $ which is pretty easy. Since $\overline A  \cap \overline B $ is closed, then $\overline A  \cap \overline B  = \overline {\overline A  \cap \overline B } $. Since $A \subseteq \overline A ,B \subseteq \overline B $, it follows that $A \cap B \subseteq \overline A  \cap \overline B $ and $\overline {A \cap B}  \subseteq \overline {\overline A  \cap \overline B } = {\overline A  \cap \overline B }$. However, I cannot solve the other half of the proof. Hope someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: Consider $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ as subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brian's example is probably the simplest. Here is another one: take $A=[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q $, $B=[0,1]\setminus A $.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. An example is as $A=(0,1),B=(1,2)$.
Clearly $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}=\{1\}$, but $\overline{A\cap B}=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

Another example: Two open squares which share an edge. (Or, rather, their closures share an edge?)